Emf of a solenoid, is it this definition we mean when we talk about a solenoid's emf?
I just need a little clarification. When we talk about the emf $\epsilon$ of a solenoid, we're talking about the energy per unit charge from the Electric Field to displace the charge from the very beginning of the solenoid (before the first turn) to the very end of the solenoid (after the last turn) ?
I suspect it's that, but it's not clearly stated in my course, nor in most of the learning website in internet. What's only stated is the definition of the induced emf (around a closed loop) but when it comes to the emf of a solenoid I can't find the explicite statement.

Induced EMF across a solenoid refers to the difference in potential energy between the start of the coil to the end of the coil, or the first turn and the last turn as told by you. Only the part across which, electric flux can link itself has an induced EMF. Here, it the the wounded coil of the solenoid.
I hope that answers your question.
